# Symfony Form ConstraintValidator and Edit/Update violation

Tags: php, symfony

I have a custom constraint validator (**@AssertUniquePhoneNumber()**) that checks if a phone number is repeated in both $phone and $second_phone fields of a Client Entity.

```
class Client {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="phone_number", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @AssertPhoneNumber(type="any")
     * @AssertUniquePhoneNumber()
     */
    protected $phone = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="second_phone", type="phone_number", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @AssertPhoneNumber(type="any")
     * @AssertUniquePhoneNumber()
     */
    protected $second_phone = null;
```

**When creating a new Client it works perfectly but the problem comes when editing/updating the Client which throws a non valid phone constraint violation.**

This is the Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/comercial/clients/edit_client/{clientId}", 
 *      requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, 
 *      defaults={"id" = 1}, 
 *      name="comercial_dashboard.clients.edit_client")
 */
public function comercialEditClient(Request $request, $clientId) {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Client');
    $client = $repository->findOneById($clientId);

    if (!$client) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'Cliente no encontrado con id ' . $clientId . '.'
        );
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(EditClientFormType::class, $client);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $client = $form->getData();
        $client->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($client);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

This is the Validator:

```
class UniquePhoneNumberValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validate($phoneNumber, Constraint $constraint) {

        // check if null
        if (null === $phoneNumber || '' === $phoneNumber) {
            return;
        }

        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('App:Client');
        $client = $repository->findByPhoneNumber($phoneNumber);

        if (!is_null($client)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->setParameter('{{ phoneNumber }}', $phoneNumber)
                    ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the constraint function:

```
// unique phone number constraint function
public function findByPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber $phoneNumber) {
    $phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->select('c')
            ->from('App:Client', 'c')
            ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
                            $qb->expr()->eq('c.phone', ':phone'), $qb->expr()->eq('c.second_phone', ':phone')
                ))
            ->setParameter('phone', $phoneUtil->format($phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat::E164))
            ->setMaxResults(1);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

**How do I tell the app to not validate the phone field when editing/updating the Client?**

Comment: Maybe you forgot to accept the answer of your previous question?

Comment: @gp_sflover Sorry, didn't know about that feature. It's done now.

Comment: Well done and don't worry, was only a reminder to help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've probably conluded yourself as well, your issue is that when editing the Client entity, your repository query returns that these phonenumbers already exists in the database (as they are stored there for the currently edited enttiy) and thus your validator returns a validation violation.

my first answer would be that this looks like something where you should be using class validator instead of generic constraint validator because your validator is in any case coupled with checking only Client entity phone numbers. So with class validator you would need to modify validation class & annotations slightly and check each phone number separately and pass also the entity id to the repository function to be excluded from the query.

if you for some reason prefer to work with this approach, you can access the entity from the constraint validation function and thus you can also here just get the entity id and pass it to the repository function.

```
public function validate($phoneNumber, Constraint $constraint) {

    // check if null
    if (null === $phoneNumber || '' === $phoneNumber) {
        return;
    }

    $currentObject = $this->context->getObject();

    $repository = $this->em->getRepository('App:Client');
    $client = $repository->findByPhoneNumber($phoneNumber, $currentObject);

    if (!is_null($client)) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ phoneNumber }}', $phoneNumber)
                ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

as said, regardless of whether you're using the class validator or the generic constraint validator, you need to update your repository function to exclude the current Client entity id from the search.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html).

Add groups to your constraints in annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="phone_number", length=50, nullable=true)
 * @AssertPhoneNumber(type="any")
 * @AssertUniquePhoneNumber(groups={"creation"})
 */
protected $phone = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="second_phone", type="phone_number", length=50, nullable=true)
 * @AssertPhoneNumber(type="any")
 * @AssertUniquePhoneNumber(groups={"creation"})
 */
protected $second_phone = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"creation", "edition"})
 */
protected $email;
```

And then define the constraints to use for validation when building the form, which is done differently depending on the way you create the form.
[The documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html) gives the following examples.

In the controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($users, array(
    'validation_groups' => array('creation'),
))->add(...);
```

In a form class:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => array('creation'),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that way, it looks much more clean.

Comment: Actually, it strictly replies to your question "How do I tell the app to not validate the phone field when editing." But do you really want to disable validation on edition? If the number is changed you still want to check that the new number doesn't exist in the database...